# How to work around @mixins naming conflicts?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, mixins, susy

I use Zurb Foundation along with Susy grids, they both have a mixin named "prefix". I'm using "bower" to include them in my project, so how to namespace them without changing in their source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine only a not so clean way:

if you can separate the .scss that is using Susy grids from the other foundation stuff, you could use grunt to compile 2 separate files, one sass run for foundation and one run for Susy grids, then eventually merge the 2 outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Sass does not offer namespacing at this point in time.  [It is a planned feature for 4.0](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/353).